# Will moving my same domain name to new host affect my subdomains?

Tags: web-hosting, website, host

For an example this is my website [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com).  i'm moving to this domain to new host but i already have [www.beta.domain.com](http://www.beta.domain.com) and beta2.domain.com.  If I move my domain to another host it will affect my sub domain or not?

Answer (score 3):

No.

You are going to only update a few DNS A records, namely `www.domain.com`, and leave all others as they were. In this case, new hosting will be used only for names which DNS RRs were updated. `www.beta.domain.com` and `beta2.domain.com` are different independent names with their own DNS records. They must be updated separately for service to be moved for those names.

Beware hosting providers often do more than just web hosting. They may host also your DNS, mail, some of them are domain registrars. If you use DNS hosting service or other services from the same provider whose web hosting service you are going to terminate, be sure you don't terminate a contract until you also move the rest of the services.